# What's the justification of multiplying colors together?

Tags: shading

In [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) model (and other shading models as well), the light color is multiplied together with the surface color component-wise. I want to know the justification for this. Is this some what related to the physics of light?

Comment: As noted in that wikipedia article, the term "Phong shading" refers *specifically* to interpolating normals across a surface and using them in lighting computations. There is no multiplying of colors in "Phong shading"; that would be a part of ["Phong lighting."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model)

Comment: Multiplying the material colour by the light is an approximation of light absorption

Comment: It is, consider the rendering equation: $$L_o = L_e + \int_{\Omega}fL_i\cos\theta\,d\omega$$
For Phong $f= k_d + k_s\frac{\cos\theta_r}{\cos\theta}$.

Answer (score 6):

When you multiply colors together the surface color acts as a filter. Remember that colors are scaled from 0 to 1.

That way with white incoming light a green object will remain looking green.

This does bring a few issues because physical light isn't as orthogonal (where the 3 primary colors are actually overlapping frequency response functions) but for the vast majority of cases you can tweak the values enough for it to stay looking realistic.

Comment: You might want to add that the problems are not a major concern as a) phong isnt really well motivated from a measurement perspective b) If you need to account for real light then RGB is an approximation anyway.